# Adding two horizontally aligned radio buttons inside a group widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a GUI using PyQt5 that will simulate some data and display some results, but since this is the first time I build a GUI with PyQt5, I find difficulty to align horizontally two radio buttons a the top left corner of the GUI.

I tried the following code, but it gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example6.py", line 30, in <module>
screen = GroupBox()
File "example6.py", line 19, in __init__
vbox.setGeometry(10,10,100,100)
TypeError: setGeometry(self, QRect): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

This is the code I tried:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class GroupBox(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setGeometry(20,20,900,700)
        self.setWindowTitle("Elevator Group Control System Simulator")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        groupbox = QGroupBox("Algorithm to use")
        groupbox.setCheckable(False)
        layout.addWidget(groupbox)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.setGeometry(10,10,100,100)
        groupbox.setLayout(hbox)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("Good Picker")
        hbox.addWidget(radiobutton)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("Naive Picker")
        hbox.addWidget(radiobutton)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = GroupBox()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: Even after applying the suggestions in the first answer, it still gives me a group of radio buttons which covers the whole GUI:

Resulting GUI

[image]

EDIT 2: After trying the suggestions in the last answer, I obtained this:

Second result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in a previous answer, the first error is because
setGeometry() expects a QRect.

If you want to align the widgets to the topleft you have to set a stretch on the right side to be compressed to the left side, and then point to the alignment of the widgets in the layout as Qt::AlignTop.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 900, 700))
        self.setWindowTitle("Elevator Group Control System Simulator")
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Algorithm to use", checkable=False)
        layout.addWidget(groupbox)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox.setLayout(hbox)
        good_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Good Picker")
        naive_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Naive Picker")
        hbox.addWidget(good_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addWidget(naive_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addStretch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = GroupBox()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Update:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 900, 700))
        self.setWindowTitle("Elevator Group Control System Simulator")
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Algorithm to use", checkable=False)
        layout.addWidget(groupbox)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox.setLayout(hbox)
        good_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Good Picker")
        naive_radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Naive Picker")
        hbox.addWidget(good_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addWidget(naive_radiobutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addStretch()
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = GroupBox()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the results I obtained are not exactly what I wanted. The frame of the group radio button still occupies the whole window, and that's not what I wanted. I included the results in my question.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan Explain yourself better, maybe an image of what you want to obtain would help.

Comment: I just added a picture of the result I obtained.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan What you get does not work for me because it is the same that I get, what I have asked you to do is to add an image of what you want to obtain as it is not clear to me. On the other hand I have added an update to my code, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`setGeometry()` expects a `QRect` as a parameter. Replace `hbox.setGeometry(10,10,100,100)` with:

```
hbox.setGeometry(QRect(10,10,100,100))
```

Note that this will require adding `from PyQt5.QtCore import *` to your imports.

Comment: It still doesn't work, it gives a group radio button which covers the whole window.